# how to make unique key not nullable in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried these are syntaxes for making unique key not nullable.

```
1 : $table -> string('email_id' , 40) -> unique() ;
    $table -> string('email_id') -> nullable(false) -> change();


2 : $table -> string('email_id' , 40) -> unique() -> nullable(false) -> change();
```

But none of them worked. It would be nice if I can find any help regarding the same.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `$table -> string('email_id' , 40) -> nullable(false) -> change() -> unique();` ?

Comment: Yes.. it gives error
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'email_i  
  d' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email  
  _id_unique`(`email_id`))

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find solution when creating table/columns then you have to solve this in PHP using [accessors and mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)

For example

```
$table -> string('email_id' , 40) -> unique() ; //email_id is unique


//now how to make not null
public function setEmailIdAttribute($value) {
    if ($value == null) ) { // will check for null 
    //do something
    } else {
        $this->attributes['email_id'] = $value;
    }
}
```

For more help check [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/schema-nullable-unique).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have written this function in my User model. but it doesn't work. where m i lacking?

Comment: What is your action when the value is null? (//do something line)

Comment: But you should do "exit" or something, because if that value is null you should't insert into database. Try to write exit or return into that.

Comment: I have written return "Null Values Error" . Still not working.

Comment: but by default columns are not null in laravel.    here is a link : http://laravelbook.com/laravel-migrations-managing-databases/

Comment: Try to replace `$value == null` to `empty($value)`

Comment: is there any other solution for the same issue?

Comment: not really. but what i have done is. by default column is set to null then i just checked that if value is "" (empty) then i will generate error for the same. as i don't want email to be null as well as "" (empty). so that way i got the solution. Thank you man for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

I have uses `$table->string('email')->unique();` it works for me.I think you have done some another mistake.

Comment: using this i can have email as unique key but i don't want it to be null in my database. as unique key can accept null values as well. that thing i don't want to be. i want unique key as not null.